# Linking to a specific section to another web page (internal)

Tags: html, web

I'm having trouble getting me web page to link to a specific section in another sub page in html. Can somebody please help.

Destination:

Link:

Counter Argument

Answer (score 0):

You must define a section in your webpage first. This can be something like...

```
<a name="counterargument"></a>
```

Then, you can create a link anywhere on your page with...

```
Click <a href="webpage.html#counterargument">here</a> to read counter argument.
```

I see this is your first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! But it still is not working for me. It will go to the next page but not the section that I want. It just automatically goes to the top of the new page